# Get meta title on category page

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

Unable to Get meta title on category page.

```
$this->getLayout()->getBlock('head')->getTitle();
```

Error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getTitle() on boolean

Magento 2.3.0

Comment: in which file are you doing it ?

Comment: Where do i have to add this? i am having the same problem on my magento 2 installation!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/145399)

Answer (score 0):

Try using these codes:

```
if(Mage::registry('current_category'))
{
   echo  Mage::registry('current_category')->getMetaTitle();
}else {

 echo $this->getTitle()
 }
```